# Error connecting Azure Service Fabric Cluster with Connect-ServiceFabricCluster

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-powershell, azure-deployment

Below is the Cmdlet I am using to connect azure fabric cluster, it was working until yesterday

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint "FQDN:19000" -KeepAliveIntervalInSec 10 -X509Credential -ServerCertThumbprint $ClientCertificateThumbprint `
-FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValue $ClientCertificateThumbprint `
-StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName My
```

**Error:**

> ErrorCode      : Unknown Message        : An error occurred during
>   this operation.  Please check the trace logs for more details. Data
>   : {} InnerException : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x8009030E): No credentials are available in the security package
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8009030E)
>                       at System.Fabric.Interop.NativeClient.IFabricClientSettings2.SetSecurityCredentials(FABRIC_SECURITY_CREDENTIALS
>   credentials)
>                       at System.Fabric.FabricClient.SetSecurityCredentialsInternal(SecurityCredentials
>   credentials)
>                       at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.WrapNativeSyncInvoke[TResult](Func`1
>   func, String functionTag, String functionArgs) TargetSite     :
>   TResult RunInMTA[TResult](System.Func`1[TResult]) StackTrace     :
>   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.RunInMTA[TResult](Func`1 func)
>                       at System.Fabric.FabricClient.InitializeFabricClient(SecurityCredentials
>   credentialArg, FabricClientSettings newSettings, String[]
>   hostEndpointsArg)
>                       at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ClusterConnection.FabricClientBuilder.Build()
>                       at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ClusterConnection..ctor(FabricClientBuilder
>   fabricClientBuilder, Boolean getMetadata)
>                       at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster.ProcessRecord()
>   HelpLink       : Source         : System.Fabric HResult        : 0

Comment: > "it was working until yesterday." Did your certificate expire?

Comment: @VaclavTurecek no certificate did not expire, the issue was I found a bug in the function that i wrote to create a new certificate